# Extract item from json with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this json link that is generated auttomatically by a software and I was trying a lot of methods to extract that number. I can't extract this **301191004942**

```
var listingID = 'http://shared1.ad-lister.co.uk/GetListingDetails.aspx?id=43baf400-dbe1-4238-b608-38303e65faea&contextId=c9d56aca-506c-40be-9068-037d0fba62c9';
```

adn this is the result

```
{"ListingId":"301191004942"}
```

any help, please?

Comment: where is that number supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Can you include the returns JSON? my current network prevents acccess

Comment: if you open that link in your browser you can see that number

Comment: If I go to the website, it's blocked by my corporate policy. Can you paste the result into your question?

Comment: I can't edit the json. I just need a way with ajax, json, etc to extract the value

Comment: then anything to do with your `listingID`?

Comment: Did you try `$.get('your url', function(r) { alert(r.listingId); });`? Of course it will work only if the said *url* is in the same domain as your app.

Comment: I need it outside of domain. With your script i get `undefined`

Comment: @adrian.axinte: It is `r.ListingId`, I think. `L` uppercase. Also, just add the "json" parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AJAX,

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://shared1.ad-lister.co.uk/GetListingDetails.aspx",
     data: {id:'43baf400-dbe1-4238-b608-38303e65faea',contextId:'c9d56aca-506c-40be-9068-037d0fba62c9'},
     dataType:"json",
     success:function(data,textStatus,jqHXR) {
         alert(data.ListingId); //now you've got it, you can do what you want.
     }
});
```

Note that this will happen asynchronously, so the code in success may run a couple seconds after the rest of the AJAX code.

Comment: He put jQuery in the tags, it's not much of an assumption.

Comment: yeah, IE is stupid, you have to implement your own [cross-domain request](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/cross-domain-ajax-and-ie)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the server allows cross-domain AJAX:

```
$.get(listingID, function(data) { 
    var listing = data.ListingId;
    // Do something with listing
}, "json");
```

Comment: but not in IE only in FF and Chrome :(

Comment: You may need to search for solutions to cross-domain AJAX. Such as running a proxy script on your own server to access the URL.

Comment: there's no error in IE, just not working. do you have any ideea? maybe another way :(

Answer (score 2):

Here you go (jQuery solution below, hope you're using jQuery)-

```
    $.ajax({   
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'text',
crossDomain: true,  
url:'http://shared1.ad-lister.co.uk/GetListingDetails.aspx?id=43baf400-dbe1-4238-b608-38303e65faea&contextId=c9d56aca-506c-40be-9068-037d0fba62c9', 
success : function(data){ 

       var item = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(item.ListingId);

        }
});
```

Comment: @adrian.axinte try finding error using IE developer tool. it should work in IE too. and you must be using jQuery. my script needs jQuery to run.

Comment: [link](http://dev.template-tuners.com/mail/demo.html) this is demo, works in ff and chrome, i can't find no error in IE